# Matlab - show corresponding values of 1st column of matrix, baring in mind the last 2 values of the 2nd column

Tags: matlab, find, max

I created a matrix with two columns, using two vectors, `f` and `PS`, that I already had:

```
M = [f PS]; %81x2 matrix
```

And then I sorted the matrix with respect to "PS" (second column), in order to have the maximum values of "PS" at the last positions of the vector:

```
M1=sortrows(M,2); %81x2 matrix
```

And I got something like this:

```
f...PS

5...83

10...136

3...357

1...985
```

Since now I assured the last two values of "PS" are indeed the maximum values, the information I want to give to the user is `1` and `3` (`f` values corresponding to the 2 maximum values of `PS`, which are at the bottom).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `end` index: `M1(end,1)` and `M1(end-1,1)` should contain `1` and `3`, respectively.

Best,